# Geotools: Rendering map with sld to svg

Tags: geotools, svg, rendering

I am generating the SVG file and then use it in jasper report print. When I try to render the map with no sld everything works great, but when I use sld there is this error:

```
2017-11-30T13:28:36.634+0100  SEVERE  null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.batik.svggen.ImageHandlerBase64Encoder.encodeImage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.svggen.ImageHandlerBase64Encoder.handleHREF(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.svggen.DefaultImageHandler.handleImage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.svggen.SimpleImageHandler.handleImage(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.batik.svggen.SVGGraphics2D.drawRenderedImage(Unknown Source)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.renderImage(StyledShapePainter.java:664)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StyledShapePainter.paint(StyledShapePainter.java:226)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PaintShapeRequest.execute(StreamingRenderer.java:3245)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread.run(StreamingRenderer.java:3572)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

To generate an SVG I am using https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/docs/src/main/java/org/geotools/render/GenerateSVG.java (same as [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/gtrenderer.html)) with added transformation for correct orientation of the image. I use an sld with wkt strings and SVG files. For embedding generated SVG to jasper reports, I had to change the version of batik to 1.8 and to update SVGGraphicFactory to use that version. The problem occurs when generating svg, so I can't convert it to png for printing.

Version of geotools 17.1

EDIT

sample data

https://www.sendspace.com/file/xku43p

Comment: can you add some sample data and the SLD you are using

Comment: added sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BATIK-1005) in Batik (the SVG renderer that GeoTools uses). This seems to be a couple of years old and might be fixed in Batik 1.9.

Comment: the problem persists with batik maven even on 1.9, but I downloaded jars and it works now. The only problem is that it draws my symbols much smaller than they are.